# Maven assembly descriptor properties

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I want to pack two or more very similar distributions, the only difference is path to data set that will be inside those distributions.

Given this example for path: **${project.basedir}/src/config/dataset1**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">

    <id>dataset1</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>

    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/config/dataset1/aaa</directory>
            <outputDirectory>conf/aaa</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/config/dataset1/bbb</directory>
            <outputDirectory>conf/bbb</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>

    <!-- MANY MORE FILESETS... -->

</assembly>
```

Now I want exactly the same assembly descriptor for different data set, for example: **${project.basedir}/src/config/dataset2**

Off course I could create two assembly descriptors. But then again I would have to keep in mind to change multiple places when needed, or worse when adding another dataset or two.

Is there a way how solve this, like creating multiple executions and passing properties to it? Or something ever nicer?

**EDIT:**
This wish item would solve everything:
https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MASSEMBLY-445

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you could use properties for this.

1. Create properties (with default value) for parts that differs between executions in `pom.xml`. E.g.:

> ```
> <properties>
>     <dataset.dir>config/dataset</dataset.dir>
> </properties>
> ```

2. Use them in your assembly descriptor just like any other property (e.g `${project.basedir}` )
3. For different executions you could:

   - use several build profiles ([Maven profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)) where override property value;
   - or pass values directly as a mvn call argument (like `mvn package -Dprop=val`)

Also, if you want to use these properties in any other place, you could populate them via placeholders in any config by using other maven plugins (for instance, [maven-resource-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)).

Comment: I know about that possibility, but that is not exactly what I was looking for. Profiles are kind of pitiful solution and I'm still hoping for something better..

Comment: you could pass any property to maven like `mvn install -Dproperty=value`, but I still think declaring all possible property values in one place (inside pom) is better.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, declaring properties inside pom is perfectly fine. Using profiles to create different distributions is more of a hack than solution and to me misuse of profiles.